# VisualStudio Express addin to enable QuickWatch?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express

The Visual Studio **QuickWatch** feature is not available in any of the *Express* editions. Is there any addon to add **QuickWatch** functionality?

Visual Studio *for-pay* Edition supports **QuickWatches**:

[image]

- Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web
- Visual C# 2010 Express Edition
- among others

do not.

---

From MSDN: [How to: Use the QuickWatch Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2(v=vs.80).aspx)

> Some users might, therefore, wonder why QuickWatch is useful. Why not simply add the variable or expression to the Watch window? Well, you could do that, but suppose you simply want to do a quick scratch calculation involving one or more variables? You don't want to clutter up the Watch window with such calculations. That's where QuickWatch comes in.
>
> Another nice feature of the QuickWatch dialog box is the fact that it's resizable. If you want to look at the members of a large object, it's often easier to expand and look at the tree QuickWatch than it is in the Watch, Locals, or Autos window.

[**Visual Studio 2005**:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> ```
> Visual Studio Edition  Visual Basic  C#   C++  J#
> =====================  ============  ===  ===  ===
> Express                No            No   No   No
> Standard               No            No   No   No
> Pro/Team               Yes           Yes  Yes  Yes
> ```

[**Visual Studio 2008**:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> ```
> Visual Studio Edition  Visual Basic  C#   C++  J#   Web Developer
> =====================  ============  ===  ===  ===  =============
> Express                No            No   Yes  No   No
> Standard               No            No   Yes  No   No
> Pro and Team           Yes           Yes  Yes  Yes  Yes
> ```

[**Visual Studio 2010**:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> ```
> Visual Studio Edition  Visual Basic  C#   F#   C++  Web Developer
> =====================  ============  ===  ===  ===  =============
> Express                No            No   No   Yes  No
> Pro and Team           Yes           Yes  Yes  Yes  Yes
> ```

[**Visual Studio 2012**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> *it's a secret*

This morning i happen to be using **Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web**.

---

### Bonus Reading

Microsoft removed the **Exception Assistant** from 2012 (which was present in 2010 Express editions):

[image]

and replaced it with nothing:

[image]

This removal was intentional, as noted on Microsoft Connect entry [*Enable Exception Assistant option missing from VS2012 Express For Desktop*](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762652/enable-exception-assistant-option-missing-from-vs2012-express-for-desktop):

> Posted by Microsoft on 17//09//2012 at 11::42 АΜ
>
> Thank you for your feedback. You are correct that we intentionally removed the exception assistant from the WDX sku for VS 2012. In 2012, pro and above are required for this functionality. You should be able to view the exception information in the watch window including the inner exception.
>
> We'll take your feedback and look into possibly adding this dialog back into the express skus in a future release but we have no plans of changing this for 2012 at this time.
>
> Marc Paine
> Visual Studio Debugger QA Lead

So that's something else that will need replacing.

[Props to this guy for figuring it out before i went nuts.](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2013/01/ive-given-up-on-visual-studio-express-2012-for-windows-desktop-heres-why/)

Comment: It seems quickwatch is back in 2013 express but the "Exception Assistant" is not.